# How embed a web widget (an AJAX form with file upload)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, iframe

I was asked to implement a generic web widget that can be embedded in arbitrary web pages that reside in other domains. The widget is a simple form generated by a Java back-end that, along with the usual name, first name and e-mail fields, uploads a file (an `<input type="file">`). Since a progress bar is required and the user must be able to cancel the file upload, I figured I needed to use AJAX.

I used the JQuery Form plugin to create a standalone page that only contained this particular widget, adapted it to my back-end and it actually worked. But! I still have to find a way to embed it in an existing page. Exactly how do you do that? I don't have much experience with front-end development so I don't know if there is a typical way to accomplish this.

I tried using an `iframe`, but couldn't find a way to style **the `iframe` itself** in such a way that the user doesn't notice it's an `iframe`, much like the HTML5 `seamless` attribute would do (latest Chrome and only tried CSS). Styling **the contents** is another matter: can an `iframe` inherit the host page's style? Is it even possible to style the `iframe` from within the host page? Cross-browser?

I also tried to AJAX-`load` the widget with JQuery and put it in the host page's DOM. This worked, but apparently only when widget (which is now part of the host page) and back-end are in the same domain, which won't be the case. I was able to include my widget with JSONP but then the file upload won't work because the back-end is still in another domain.

So I've got style-related issues with the `iframe` solution, and cross-domain issues with the AJAX solution. Maybe I'm making things too complicated, I don't know.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Where are you uploading the file? to the server that hosts the widget or each web page uploading the file to the server it's hosted on?

Comment: @JacobAmerz: to the server that hosts the widget.

Comment: I guess it would have to be an iframe, and if you wrap in in a div, it can be styled any way you want really. kyle_sevenoaks.bitbucket.org uses an iFrame to pull in the other website, but is styled to fit the theme.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks: in what way are they styled to fit the theme? Can you change fonts and colors for those websites? I need a little more information; your website isn't helping much.

Comment: The content within the iFrame cannot be accessd by your local CSS or anything, I must have read your question wrong.